# Putting each value in a table

Tags: r

I have an r code where I am printing the values and doing a small calculation on it.

```
    for (j in sample.data1$SENTIMENT_STRENGTH_91D) {
    i = (j - max(sample.data1$SENTIMENT_STRENGTH_91D))/C
     }
```

this prints out each value of i. How can I put these values into a vector inside the loop? 
I have tried this code but it only gives the last values

```
for (j in sample.data1$SENTIMENT_STRENGTH_91D) {
 i = (j - max(sample.data1$SENTIMENT_STRENGTH_91D))/C
 D <- c(i)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `for` loop to the following:

```
D = numeric(0)
for (j in sample.data1$SENTIMENT_STRENGTH_91D) {
    i = (j - max(sample.data1$SENTIMENT_STRENGTH_91D))/C
    D <- c(D, i)
}
```

But it turns out growing an object in a `for` loop in R is very slow. You probably don't even need a `for` loop. You can try taking advantage of R's vectorization:

```
x <- sample.data1$SENTIMENT_STRENGTH_91D

D <- (x - max(x))/C
```